# How to convert all strings inside a object in to uppercase in C#

Tags: c#, string, uppercase

I'm getting data like this

```
var alldest = cc.returnallfullDestinations(mainElement).Split('|');
```

`returnallfullDestionations` is a `string` and this `alldest` contains upper case and lower case strings now. I want to convert them all into uppercase after the line of code above. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

`Split('|')` will result in `string[]`. What you can do is to continue what you have done using `LINQ` `Select` and `string.ToUpper()`:

```
var result = alldest.Select(x => x.ToUpper());
```

Comment: thanx to your answer.my way is working properly.thank you again.I upvoted your answer.it is a good one.

Comment: @bill OK, great! :) yes, it is true that you could also reverse the `ToUpper` and `Split` since the input is `string` your method is equally valid :)

Answer (score 1):

job done..this is how we can do that.

```
var alldest = cc.returnallfullDestinations(mainElement).ToUpper().Split('|');
```

thanx all

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `Split` is the standard `string.Split` method (= alldest is `string[]`) and you can use LINQ expressions you could simply write

```
var upper = alldest.Select(s => s.ToUpper());
```